# jquery code doesnt seem to respond

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this may seem to have been often asked...but sometimes you are at your wit's end not able to make out what is going wrong. Like the code below. The jquery does not seem to work.

Help appreciated.

Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="javascript/text">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#buy').click(function(){$('#buyform').fadeIn('fast');});
$('#sell').click(function(){$('#sellform').fadeIn('fast');});
$('#rent').click(function(){$('#rentform').fadeIn('fast');});
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.options ul li{listing-style-type:none;display:inline;margin:5px;margin-bottom:3px;background-  color:purple;color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:5px;}
#buyform,#sellform,#rentform{display:none}
#buy,#sell,#rent{cursor:pointer;}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="topsearchbox">
<div class="options">
    <ul><li id="buy">Buy</li><li id="sell">Sell</li><li id="rent">Rent</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form">
<div class="formchange">

    <div id="buyform">
        <form name="searchform" action="" method="POST">
        <label class="formlabel">Property</label>
        <select><option></option></select><select><option></option></select><select><option></option></select>
        <input type="submit" name="formsubmit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="sellform">
        <form name="searchform" action="" method="POST">
        <label class="formlabel">Property</label>
        <select><option></option></select><select><option></option></select><select><option></option></select>
        <input type="submit" name="formsubmit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="rentform">
        <form name="searchform" action="" method="POST">
        <label class="formlabel">Property</label>
        <select><option></option></select><select><option></option></select><select><option></option></select>
        <input type="submit" name="formsubmit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Would love to know what I am doing wrong !

Comment: When you are testing this is it in a `.html` file that you are just double clicking on?  The protocol-less URLS only work if the file is being accessed from a web server (via http or https)

Comment: _does not seem to work._ - succinct, accurate and totally useless. Explain what should happen and what is actually happening. Include any error messages on the browser console.

Comment: @Jason. Am testing on local machine.And a PHP file

Comment: @mike, the sellform, buyform and rentform divs need to fadein on click but doesnt happen

Comment: @jason Same condition from server too..

Comment: It seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/b6m5j/ Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 reasons both pretty easy to fix.

1. in your script declairation you have

   `<script type="javascript/text">` this should be `<script type="text/javascript">`
2. You closing the jQuery document ready function in the wrong order you have

   `)};` it should be  `});`

Enjoy

Comment: 2. Ummm, where did you saw that?

Comment: @h.coates. Thanks a ton! I had updated the brackets through an edit earlier. But the "text/javascript" seemed to do the trick !

Comment: You don't need to write `type` element at all. Use `<script>` only, it is perfectly valid and recommended.

Comment: Thats a great bit advice Pavel. Will def follow that. Should help stop inadvertent errors like the one in this case.

Comment: @user3526204, removing the type attribute is only valid in HTML 5, remember to use it when you want to target backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Add you code inside `<script> ..code..</script>`

Try this way

```
<div class="options">
        <ul>
            <li id="buy" data-div="buyform">Buy</li>
            <li id="sell" data-div="sellform">Sell</li>
            <li id="rent" data-div="rentform">Rent</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

SCript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.options ul li').click(function () {
        var con = $(this).data('div');
        $('#' + con).fadeIn('slow').siblings('div').fadeOut('slow')
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G7Ws7/6/)

Comment: @user3526204 add you code inside `<script> ..code..</script>`

Comment: Yours is also definitely a good option but as I am not too experienced in jquery, I needed to know where my query was exactly going wrong. I got the answer. Thanks to you for your answer too. Dont know if I can mark multiple answers as right here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Script block has error in bracketing as well as in type. Below is the solution.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#buy').click(function(){$('#buyform').fadeIn('fast');});
$('#sell').click(function(){$('#sellform').fadeIn('fast');});
$('#rent').click(function(){$('#rentform').fadeIn('fast');});
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. Your answer is right too. I have already accepted h.coates answer which is the same. Dont know if I am allowed to mark multiple answers as the right ones.

Comment: Yes, you can mark multiple answers as the right ones.

Comment: Not able to, Dotnet. When I mark one the other marking goes away !

Comment: Oh, sorry [user352604](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3526204/user3526204), i checked and found that only one solution can be marked as answer. But you can up vote my solution if you found it correct and useful. Thanks.